# Exceljs+nodejs to serve excel stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

Suppose I want to use exceljs to serve excel to web clients. Also, suppose that I am using streaming (due to the files being potentially large and not wanted to keep them in memory).

Is it possible to find out what the Content-Length header should be? Because without this, I can't see the download progress spinner from chrome.

Example code:

```
app.get('/some/route', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="file.xlsx"',
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    "Content-Length" : inf //this is what I want!!
  })
  var workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ stream: res })
  var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('some-worksheet')
  worksheet.addRow(['foo', 'bar']).commit()
  worksheet.commit()
  workbook.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
res.set({
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="ireshansexcel.xlsx"',
  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
});

 const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
 const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Survey');
 //your excel worksheet content
 //commit everything
 let fileBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
 res.send(fileBuffer);
```

I have been using `writeBuffer()` method in exceljs and seems it's working fine with progress spinner. But I have worked with small files. But you can test this approach.
I used this approach because above you mentioned method didn't worked for me in azure functions.

Comment: buffers have a 1 gb max in nodejs I think, and as I mentioned, it must use streaming as some of these excel files are massive

Comment: oh.. I see, then you have to use streams indeed.

Comment: which is what i was using, but I can't figure out the content-length header

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @ireshan pathirana answer, `workbook.xlsx.write` can be used, no file buffer needed (

```
res.set({
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="ireshansexcel.xlsx"',
  'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
});

 const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
 const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Survey');
 //your excel worksheet content
 //commit everything
 workbook.xlsx.write(res);
```